# Alinhamento de imagens no Markdown

Tags: markdown, rmarkdown

Estou tentanto inserir três imagens no R usando markdown, mas preciso que aparecam todas juntas uma ao lado da outra. Qual a sintaxe a ser usada, estou conseguindo colocar uma abaixo da outra.

```
[example](/example.png), [example](/example.png), [example](/example.png)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O markdown por si só apenas gera as imagens na sequencia e dependendo do limite do tamanho da tela aonde será exibido o HTML ele vai quebrar as imagens (o limite da tela, não o markdown), o que posso lhe sugerir para forçar manter seria usar tabelas (se a versão do markdown tiver suporte):

```
| Imagem 1 | Imagem 2 | Imagem 3 |
|----------|----------|----------|
| ![example](/example.png) | ![example](/example.png) | ![example](/example.png) |
```

Resultado (agora tabelas e alinhamento também funcionam nos sites da rede):

| Imagem 1 | Imagem 2 | Imagem 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: example] | [image: example] | [image: example] |

Se quiser alinhas as imagens a esquerda ou direita use o `:`, exemplo:

```
| nativo   | esquerda | centro   | direita  |
|----------|:---------|:--------:|---------:|
| ![example](/example.png) | ![example](/example.png) | ![example](/example.png) | ![example](/example.png) |
```

Resultado:

| nativo | esquerda | centro | direita |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: example] | [image: example] | [image: example] | [image: example] |

A imagem 2 vai ficar alinhado a esquerda da coluna e a imagem 3 vai alinhar a direita da outra coluna.

Vale lembrar que nem todo gerador ou visualizador de markdown suportará todas funcionalidades, ainda mais dependendo de versão, logo não sei dizer se no https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ isso terá suporte.

Comment: Deu certo aqui @Guilherme Nascimento. Obrigado!

Answer (score -3):

Você poderia utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
<div align="center">

![Nome da imagem caso ela não carregue](Copie aqui o link da sua imagem)

</div>
```